# Replace item with span Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code

```js
$('.main_image a').each(function() {
 $(this+':last-child').replaceWith($('<span></span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_image">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="##"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="main_image">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="##"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I want for each `.main_image` to replace the last `a` into a `span`. I try to do it in Jquery but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use each method. Simply select the target element and replace them:

```
$('.main_image a:last-child')//selects each last a tag of main_image
  .replaceWith($('<span></span>'));//then replace with
```